# WCF Services hosted in IIS is not accessing using mobile network?

Tags: wcf, iis, mobile

WCF Services hosted in IIS is not accessing using mobile network???

I have WCF services hosted in IIS server and i have a windows 8 App as client for consuming the WCF service. when my laptop and mobile is Connected with Wifi. My Mobile app getting the data from Service but when i turned off the wifi for mobile only and trying to access the wcf service from mobile internet then i am not able to get the data.
Can anyone know how to expose the WCF service for any kind of network??

Comment: Could you please describe where is the service hosted in Laptop? If you turn off the wifi, does it affect the network connectivity of server ?. If your server is up and running, then you should be able to access the wcf service irrespective of the medium (Mobile Data Services or Mobile WiFi)

Comment: WCF service is hosted in my IIS server of the laptop and i am consuming the service by my mobile App. if mobile and laptop are in the same network then only communication is happening. with mobile network i am not able to consume my service... and one more thing on my laptop i don't have the static ip and my laptop is only connected to internet through wifi.